# Why is this variable automatically rounding?

Tags: python, rounding

```
#Y=mx+b
x1, y1 = input("X1,Y1: ").split(",")
x2, y2 = input("X2,Y2: ").split(",")
print("\n")

Xdif = (int(x1) - int(x2))
Ydif = (int(y1) - int(y2))

Yslope = (int(Ydif) * int(x1))

if(Xdif == 0):
  print("Slope is Undefined")
else:
  Slope = (int(Yslope) / int(Xdif))
  if(int((Slope*10) % 10) == 0):
    SlopeN, bad = str(Slope).split(".")
    print("Slope:",SlopeN)
  else:
    print("Slope:",Slope)
    Why = (int(y1) - int(Slope))
    print(Why)
```

I'm new to stack overflow but have been using python for about two months now. I'm relatively experienced but have no idea why when printing the variable "Why"it automatically rounds. I am creating a script to find the slope-intercept form from two points on a graph. Any help is appreciated.
-Noah

*Edit* changed variable name

Comment: a difference between integers is always "rounded"...

Comment: Is your variable really named "why?" ??? - but anyway: as Jean-François mentions, an integer, by definition, has no decimal part...

Comment: round in integers? or you want to convert it into floats?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Integer division rounds in Python 2 and converts to a float in Python 3.

Comment: Replace all occurences of `int` with `float` and you should be good to go.

Comment: I'm using python 3.6.1

Comment: Perhaps you thought up to now `int` would be there to get a number from a string? But it's there to get an _integer_ number from a string. Try inputting e.g. `3.14` or sth like that in your code - it will throw an error, as this is not castable to `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

int(n) will return an Integer. If n is a float, it will be truncated.

The difference between two integers is (surprisingly...) an integer, so yes the final result is a truncated Integer.

Consider using float(n) instead of int(n).

Comment: they're casting _strings_ to `int`, not arbitrary numbers. so if `n` is a (string representation of a) float, it will throw an error.

Comment: Thanks, don't know why I was so foolish

Comment: Changing the last to instances of int to float makes the script work

Comment: Might be true - but it's still ugly, as your script is full of casts for nothing. Apply a meaningful cast right after the `input()` function, because _there_ you want to change type: string is not good for calculation, so choose a type of your needs. And from there on you can leave the casting away.